# Add polyline on button click

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I'd like to add a poly line to my map but can't seem to get it to render on button click. Here is the code I currently have:

```
<button onClick={
                    function(){
                        console.log(asset.past);
                        var pathLine = new L.Polyline(asset.past, {
                        color: 'red',
                        weight: 3,
                        opacity: 0.5,
                        smoothFactor: 1
                      }
                    );
                    leafletMap.addLayer(pathLine);}
                  }
                  className="btn btn-info eachBtn">Go</button>
```

Thanks, Ed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you're trying to manage the map state outside the context of react-leaflet.  I'm not even sure if you're using the [react-leaflet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-leaflet) package or sort of trying to roll your own react website that happens to have leaflet.

If you are indeed using [react-leaflet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-leaflet), you should be maintaining a list of polylines that you want to render in the component's state or a property that is updated and sent by a parent component.  Then, in your render function you would iterate over these polylines and render each of them as react-leaflet polylines.

Something like this:

```
render() {
  return (
    <Map 
      center={[51.505, -0.09]} 
      zoom={13} 
      >
      <TileLayer
        attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        url='http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
        />
      {this.state.polylines.map((positions, idx) => 
        <Polyline key={`polyline-${idx}`} positions={positions} />
      )}
    </Map>
  );
}
```

Also, see the example [over here](https://jsfiddle.net/q2v7t59h/413/) of a similar react-leaflet application that adds markers after points are clicked on the map.

Comment: Got it working now which I definitely could not have done without your help! Your are awesome and I hope you have an awesome day, week, month, year and life!!!